# Why does this code work, even though in my mind this should only add one space per item with the join function, but it aligns perfectly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking for an explanation for why this works, as I am very confused. I did this by accident and got the correct solution so i need this clarifying.Please see my code below:

```
def backward_string_by_word(text: str) -> str:
    a = ""
    words = text.split(" ")
    a = [a + i[::-1] for i in words]
    b = " ".join(a)
            

    return b
        


print("Example:")
print(backward_string_by_word("hello    world"))

# These "asserts" are used for self-checking
assert backward_string_by_word("") == ""
assert backward_string_by_word("world") == "dlrow"
assert backward_string_by_word("hello world") == "olleh dlrow"
assert backward_string_by_word("hello   world") == "olleh   dlrow"
assert backward_string_by_word("welcome to a game") == "emoclew ot a emag"

print("The mission is done! Click 'Check Solution' to earn rewards!")
```

With the join function, why does it join the words together with the exact spaces, when I only expected it to join them one space and throw the program off? Because when I join them it adds the correct amount of spaces, I also tried this with numbers and it switches the number I put in with the amount of spaces in the string.

Comment: Have you count the number of 'words' once Splitted. I assume that two spaces creates two words. The first ok, the second probably empty or null (i have not m'y computer to test).

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that initially defining `a` is unnecessary:

```
a = ""
```

Specifically:

```
a = [a + i[::-1] for i in words]
```

Can be replaced with just:

```
a = [i[::-1] for i in words]
```

The reasoning is that `i[::-1]` is already a (reversed) string or `str` -- so, concatenating it with the empty string `""` is clearly redundant.

Proof:

```
def backward_string_by_word(text: str) -> str:
    words = text.split(" ")
    result = " ".join(i[::-1] for i in words)
    return result

# or whatever
assert backward_string_by_word("hello   world") == "olleh   dlrow"
assert backward_string_by_word("welcome to a game") == "emoclew ot a emag"
```

To replace multiple (consecutive) spaces with just single space, I would add `if i` to the `list` or `generator` comprehension, so that empty `str.split` results can be discarded:

```
def backward_string_by_word(text: str) -> str:
    words = text.split(" ")
    result = " ".join(i[::-1] for i in words if i)
    return result

# note assert is different here!
assert backward_string_by_word("hello   world") == "olleh dlrow"
assert backward_string_by_word("welcome to a game") == "emoclew ot a emag"
```

Comment: Oh, it's *absolutely* unnecessary. Whoever wrote this seemed to think that `i[::-1]` was not a string, but concatenating it with the string `""` would make the result a string.

Comment: @chepner thanks. I updaeted the answer with a brief explanation, based on this.